# MongoDB query for next x hours

Tags: node.js, mongodb, date

i know i can use $lt or $gt but i am using json to configure lots of *bots* (bot-ish).

these bots have to query next x hours but because i am using json, i can't update date after i send json, so if i create a date at first it does query next 4 hour, after one hour it queries for next 3 hour, do i have to update and send json every x seconds or is there a easier way to do it?

note: i just pass config as reference, not stringifying.

example bot config with query:

```
{
  botConfig: {
    query: {
      username: /^X/,
      timestamp: {
        $lt: new Date(Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 4)
      },
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just added a getter to timestamp property

```
get timestamp() {
  return { $lt: new Date(Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 12) };
},
```